# Failed authentication with Ruby HTTPClient

Tags: ruby

I have this very simple Ruby code which makes Ruby POST request.
For some reason it creates 2 requests - one authentication error and one successful request:

```
  def execute         
    request = HTTPClient.new()
    request.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
    request.set_auth('https://test.net/api', 'user', 'pass')

    request_body = File.read("requests/xml/req.xml")

    response = request.post('https://test.net/api', request_body, {'Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'cache-control' => 'no-cache'}).body
    puts 'called'
  end
```

I suppose that some configuration if missing for HTTPClient?

Can you advise how I can fix this?

Comment: One scenario is that your authentication actually fails (1st request) and you get redirected by the server (2nd requests) if your http-client is configured to follow redirects

Answer (score 0):

This is [an expected behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication). The client won't send the credentials unless they are required. When the client gets a 401 status code then it sends the request again but now with the credentials.

You can force some clients to send the credentials on the first request.

Ruby's HTTPClient has a `force_basic_auth` that does that.